# HttpPstedFileBase value is null in asp .net MVC controller while trying to upload a file using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase

Following is the `JQuery` code that I'm using:

```
$('#btnVideoUpload').click(
    function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("AssociatedVideoFile", $('#AssociatedVideoFile')[0]);
        console.log($('#AssociatedVideoFile')[0]);
        xhr.open("POST", "/Admin/UploadVideo/", true);
        xhr.send(fd);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
            alert(event.target.response);
        }, false);
    });
```

Here is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UploadVideo(HttpPostedFileBase AssociatedVideoFile){
    var fupVideoFile = AssociatedVideoFile;
    //other code...
}
```

When I run this code, the value of `AssociatedVideoFile` is always null. Can anyone help me with the issue and point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `$('#AssociatedVideoFile')[0]` to `$('#AssociatedVideoFile')[0].files[0]` or `$('#AssociatedVideoFile').prop('files')[0]` (also using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on form tag). Probably you had mistakenly tried to get object array index instead of file array index from `"AssociatedVideoFile`.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto: Got it working! I did not realize that I was trying to get the object array index. Thank you very much for pointing out!